# How to make "Tree Dropdown" in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I am trying to implement tree dropdown option. I am being able to show options that i have in my database. But when clicked it is not being clicked or posted. Here is what i have done.

I have send array data from controller like this:

```
    $this->data['category_tree'] = $this->general->get_category_tree();
```

and the function for this in general is:

```
            public function get_category_tree()
           {
$this->ci->db->where('is_display','1');
$query = $this->ci->db->get('product_categories');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
{

    foreach($query->result() as $cat)
    {
        if($cat->parent_id=='0'){
            //category
            $categories_arr[$cat->id] = array('id' => $cat->id, 'parent_id'=>$cat->parent_id ,'name' => $cat->name, 'subcat' => array());
        }else{
            //subcategory;
            $categories_arr[$cat->parent_id]['subcat'][] = array('id' => $cat->id, 'parent_id' => $cat->parent_id, 'name' => $cat->name);
        }
    }
    return $categories_arr;
}               
return false;
   }
```

And in view:

```
       <fieldset >
        <h4>Choose Category</h4>
        <div class="ddmenu"> <a id="chooseCategory" href="javascript:void(0)" class="main_btn">
          <?php if($this->input->post('categoryName',TRUE)){echo $this->input->post('categoryName',TRUE);}?>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <?php
                if($category_tree){
                    foreach($category_tree as $category)
                    {
                        ?>
            <li <?php if(!$category['subcat']){ ?> onclick="addThis('<?php echo $category['name']; ?>','<?php echo $category['id']; ?>','0')" <?php } else { ?>class="dropdown-submenu"<?php }?>> <a href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
              <?php if($category['subcat']){ ?>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
                <?php foreach($category['subcat'] as $subcat){?>
                <li onclick="addThis('<?php echo $subcat['name']; ?>','<?php echo $category['id']; ?>','<?php echo $subcat['id']; ?>')"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-clickable="data-clickable" tabindex="-1"> <?php echo $subcat['name']; ?> </a> </li>
                <?php } ?>
              </ul>
              <?php } ?>
            </li>
            <?php
      }

    ?>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>
        </fieldset>
```

and I am getting this view

[image: Dropdown option]

But when I click it, nothing happens. How can I make it posted. I have loaded the script. Is it problem with it?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand Javascript well enough, but what exactly is the addThis supposed to accomplish? I don't see anything in here that looks like a redirect. Unless it's in a script somewhere else in the page that triggers on select?

Comment: @Joe Yeah that addThis is supposed to add the clicked option . But it aint working. I am also trying with JS for the first time. Not so familiar with it. That's why I am asking is there any other easy fix?

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like: onclick="window.location('<?php echo base_url() . $category['name'] . '/' . $category['id']; ?>','0')"

Comment: @Joe didn't work. Just cut that JS and all. Now how would you work for tree drop down here with those data. Do you wanna see the aray data? The drop down structure is there in picture

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I gave you the wrong JS. I didn't want to recreate your entire scenario, so I just did the following:

```
<?php 

$name = 'cat';
$cat_id = 12;
$subcat_id = 11;
$subcat_name = 'Subcat';
?>
<ul>
<li onclick=location.href='<?php echo base_url() . $name . '/' . $cat_id . '/' . $subcat_id; ?>'> 
    <a href="javascript:;" data-clickable="data-clickable" tabindex="-1"> <?php echo $subcat_name; ?> </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Of course, your setup is slightly different, but you should be able to replace the variables as appropriate. This did redirect me to a non-existent, but correctly requested page.